# Why the alloc and the init may return the different object when creating the new object?

Tags: ios, objective-c

As the ios's document says that we should creating a new object following

```
NSObject *newObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

And never create a object like this

```
NSObject *someObject = [NSObject alloc];
[someObject init];
```

It says that the `init` may possible return the different than `alloc`,so I'm confused that why or in what case they return the different object?Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take as an example the huge number of initWith... methods of the NSString class. Some are very specialised, and would like to return a specialised object. alloc cannot know that. So [NSString alloc] returns a generic NSString object, and each initWith method can return some specialised object instead.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is allowed so that your class could produce a stand-in object for the one being created. You may want to do that for several reasons:

- **Object Caching** - If you need to create and release the same objects often, for example, when you create wrapper objects for numeric values, you could store object instances for reuse, and return them when requested. If you make your objects immutable, you could save significant amounts of memory by sharing your objects.
- **Returning a subclass** - There are multiple design reasons for doing this, for example, to implement hidden functionality that is compatible with the interface of the object being returned, such as copy-on-write.
- **Returning `nil`** - You are allowed to do this to indicate failure of your `init` function.

Comment: Sounds very interesting, especially on the hidden functionality part, could you please write a few lines of code as to roughly show how that could be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Because

NSObject *someObject = [NSObject alloc];

All alloc does is allocate memory for the object. At this point in time there is no actual NSObject type, just a region of memory. This doesn't have any direct consequence if you immediately call init but you might fail to realize the init wasn't called and attempt to use the object without initialization.

The other answer has an even better reason, you might not get the same object back from init.